# Which class of algorithms does this problem belong to?

Tags: algorithms

Which class of algorithms would this sort of a problem belong to? If I had to pick up a book on algorithms, which topic should I be looking at to find more problems of this nature and their explanation?

*Given the current location on of the horse (or whatever the thing is that moves two spaces horizontally and one vertically) on a chess board, say, (x1, y1), how many steps would you need to move it to reach a destination location (x2, y2)?*

Comment: You should better ask which class of algorihm can solve this problem. Usually a problem can be solved by different classes of algorothms.

Comment: That chess piece is called a Knight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a pathfinding algorithm which would be part of graph theory.

Example algorithms include A* and Dijkstra's algorithm.